# Editing string with analyze-string in XSLT

Tags: php, xml, regex, xslt

I am using the following function in php to load an xml doc into an xslt document, output xml, and replace document.xml in the word docx:

```
$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDocument->load('xml/' . $xmlfile);

$xsltDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xsltDocument->load($xsltFile);

$xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltProcessor->importStylesheet($xsltDocument);
```

So I usually use this function in the XSLT file to pull an XML var:

```
<xsl:value-of select="PORT_REQUEST/WICIS/REMARKS" />
```

However, because XML vars are loaded directly into the XSLT document, I cannot use my friendly PHP reg exp's, and I am struggling greatly trying to figure out how to make this work. I just need to pull the XML var (Telephone # in 1112223333 format) and put it in 111-222-3333 format.

This is what i have:

```
            <xsl:analyze-string select="PORT_REQUEST/NUMBER_PORTABILITY/ADMINISTRATIVE/ATN"
                regex="(^.{3})|(.{4}$)|((?<=(^.{3}))(.*?)(?=(.{4}$)))">

                  <xsl:matching-substring>
                  <xsl:number value="regex-group(1)" format="001"/>
                  <xsl:number value="regex-group(2)" format="001"/>
                  <xsl:number value="regex-group(3)" format="0001"/>
                  </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
```

And it is not working, what I get instead of the re-formatted telephone number variable is an empty xml document, as whatever error I'm causing kills the entire thing.
Help

Comment: Good question so far, but whenever you type "it is not working," you need to ask: have I told exactly what result I expected, and what result I got instead? In this case, the latter seems to be missing.

Comment: Result I expect: "I just need to pull the XML var (Telephone # in 1112223333 format) and put it in 111-222-3333 format." And what I got was an empty xml file, every time. It just kills the whole thing, any the only error message I get is "must have at least 1 root node"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have access to XSLT2? By default PhP is likely to have XSLT1 unless you have hooked up saxon's XSLT2 engine somewhere. In which case `xsl:analyze-string` and `replace()` are not available, and you want something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="PORT_REQUEST/NUMBER_PORTABILITY/ADMINISTRATIVE/ATN">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,3)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,4,3)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(.,7)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: YES FINALLY! Thank you, you are probably correct about the XSLT version causing the error, as xsl:analyze-string and replace() both caused fatal errors. I always love a simple solution

Comment: So why did you say you got an empty file, rather than telling us that you got a fatal error? It's very hard to help when you're given wrong information.

Comment: Welcome David Carlisle! It's fantastic to have both you and Michael Kay here.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:analyze-string` is overkill for this situation. Instead, *assuming you have XSLT 2.0,* I would use a single regexp replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(PORT_REQUEST/WICIS/REMARKS,
             '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', '$1-$2-$3')" />
```

This parses any 10-digit number into the 3-3-4 blocks, and outputs them with hyphens between them.

However as @David Carlisle pointed out, XSLT 2.0 is not normally available with PHP. So neither `xsl:analyze-string` nor `replace()` is available. See his answer.

Comment: Thank you, testing in here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it does work, but my output docx file (with the replaced document.xml file within) only holds a third of the content it should, still some error.

Comment: just confirmed the replace function is causing the error, still open to answers

Comment: @David is spot-on in pointing out that PHP doesn't offer XSLT 2.0, which I overlooked. Did you neglect to tell us about some fatal errors?